# remote_api in google app engine is the best way to store data?

Tags: django, google-app-engine

i don't know what  the remote_api will do

thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can read about remote_api here: http://code.google.com/appengine/articles/remote_api.html

At a high level, it allows you to write code which interacts with your appengine application code and datastore without having to go through the request/response model.